# Filtering an ObjectQuery<T> dynamically on DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following method that is used to filter an ObjectQuery by date using EF:

```
public List<T> FilterObjectSetByDate<T>(ObjectQuery<T> inputQuery, string dateColumn) where T : class
{
    ObjectQuery<T> filteredQuery = inputQuery.Where("(dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, it" + dateColumn + ")) = @p0)");
    ObjectParameter objParam = new ObjectParameter("p0", DateTime.Now);
    filteredQuery.Parameters.Add(objParam);

    return filteredQuery.ToList();
}
```

Which leads to the following error:

```
'dateadd' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function.
```

Is there any way to return a list of records for a given day (ignoring the time portion of the DateTime) using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured this out this morning:

```
Where("SqlServer.datediff('DAY'," + dateColumn + ", @p{1}) = 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

[Googling](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f32f3311-350d-4c2d-a4fd-c801918d36b1/) suggests using `"SqlServer.dateadd...` instead of just `"dateadd...`, similarly for `datediff`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but it won't allow the use of an int as the second argument of SqlServer.datediff...looking for a workaround now

Comment: Hah thanks... I was just going to delete this since you found the answer anyway, but I'll accept a small amount of credit for getting you started :)

Comment: yeah...was gonna upvote when I accepted my answer anyway :) downvote totally undeserved!