# Filtering Date in where clause of EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a EntityDataSource and I have to filter all items older 30 days.

my approach on my MSSQL database:

```
protected void EntityDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    EntityDataSource1.WhereParameters.Clear();    
    EntityDataSource1.Where = "DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), it.CreateDate) < 30" ;
}
```

gives the error: *DATEDIFF cannot be resolved into a valid type or function*

Comment: Is this a T-SQL database, like SQL Server?  DATEDIFF() is a T-SQL command.  If you're using an Oracle DB, however, that function doesn't exist, and is done as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406397/datediff-function-in-oracle

Comment: @user1895086 _TO_DATE cannot be resolved into a valid type or function_

Comment: Are you able to do it in the db with a query ? because Entity is really fun but you have to use function that can be converted into a db query, the one you are using specificly

Comment: @AntoinePelletier yes, `SELECT *  FROM [User]  WHERE   DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), CreateDate) < 30` works

Comment: You can use `WHERE it.CreateDate<= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;`, only if `it.CreateDate` is type datetime or timestamp

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki `System.Data.EntitySqlException` invalid syntax

Comment: What type is `it.CreateDate`?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki `CreateDate` is type of `DateTime` - i think `NOW()` and `INTERVAL` works with MySQL only

Comment: Try `SqlServer.DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), it.CreateDate) < 30"`

Answer (score 1):

You need call `SqlServer.DATEDIFF()`, use this:

```
EntityDataSource1.Where = "SqlServer.DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), it.CreateDate) < 30" ;
```

instead

```
EntityDataSource1.Where = "DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), it.CreateDate) < 30" ;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259857/filtering-an-objectqueryt-dynamically-on-datetime) you find similar question but with `DATEADD` function